# Inserting into MySQL from Python - Errors

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to write a record into a MySQL DB where I have defined table `jobs` as:

```
CREATE TABLE jobs(
   job_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   job_title VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
   job_url VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL,
   job_location VARCHAR(150),
   job_salary_low DECIMAL(25) DEFAULT(0),
   job_salary_high DECIMAL(25), DEFAULT(0),
   company VARCHAR(150),
   job_posted DATE,
   PRIMARY KEY ( job_id )
);
```

The code I am testing with is:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO jobs VALUES(DEFAULT, '"+jobTitle+"','"
    +jobHref+"',"+salaryLow+","+salaryHigh+",'"+company+"',"
    +jobPostedAdjusted+"','"+salaryCurrency+"';")
print(cur.fetchall())
```

The errors that I am getting are:

```
pydev debugger: starting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.0.2013032300\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1397, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.0.2013032300\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1090, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) #execute the script
  File "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\PythonScripts\PythonScripts\testFind.py", line 25, in <module>
    +jobPostedAdjusted+"','"+salaryCurrency+"';")
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

What is the best way insert this record? Thanks.

Comment: please don't build a query as a string, use parameterized queries so that you don't leave yourself open to sql injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best way insert this record?

Use `%s` placeholders, and pass your parameters as a separate list, then `MySQLdb` does all the parameter interpolation for you.

For example...

```
params = [jobTitle,
          jobHref,
          salaryLow,
          salaryHigh,
          company,
          jobPostedAdjusted,
          salaryCurrency]
cur.execute("INSERT INTO jobs VALUES(DEFAULT, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", params)
```

This also protects you from SQL injection.

---

**Update**

> I have `print(cur.fetchall())` after the `cur.execute....` When the
>   code is run, it prints empty brackets such as `()`.

`INSERT` queries don't return a result set, so `cur.fetchall()` will return an empty list.

> When I interrogate the DB from the terminal I can see nothing has been changed.

If you're using a transactional storage engine like InnoDB, you have explicitly commit the transaction, with something like...

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(...)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT ...")
conn.commit()
```

If you want to `INSERT` lots of rows, it's much faster to do it in a single transaction...

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(...)
cur = conn.cursor()
for i in range(100):
    cur.execute("INSERT ...")
conn.commit()
```

...because InnoDB (by default) will sync the data to disk after each call to `conn.commit()`.

> Also, does the `commit;` statement have to be in somewhere?

The `commit` statement is interpreted by the MySQL client, not the server, so you won't be able to use it with `MySQLdb`, but it ultimately does the same thing as the `conn.commit()` line in the previous example.

Comment: The penny isn't dropping. I've tried this but to no avail? I have `print(cur.fetchall())` after the `cur.execute...`. When the code is run, it prints empty brackets such as `()`. When I interrogate the DB from the terminal I can see nothing has been changed. Also, does the `commit;` statement have to be in somewhere?

Comment: Your updated answer clears things up; also having added `con.commit()` is now writing records to the DB. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error message say it all:

> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects

Python does not convert automagicaly floats to string. Your best friend here *could* be [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

```
>>> "INSERT INTO jobs VALUES(DEFAULT, '{}', '{}')".format("Programmer", 35000.5)
"INSERT INTO jobs VALUES(DEFAULT, 'Programmer', '35000.5')"
```

*But*, please note that insertion of user provided data in a SQL string without any precautions might lead to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)! Beware... That's why `execute` provide its own way of doing, protecting you from that risk. Something like that:

```
>>> cursor.execute("INSERT INTO jobs VALUES(DEFAULT, '%s', '%f', "Programmer", 35000.5)
```

For a complete discussion about this, search the web. For example http://love-python.blogspot.fr/2010/08/prevent-sql-injection-in-python-using.html

---

And, btw, the float type is mostly for scientific calculation. But it is usually not suitable for monetary values, due to rounding errors (that's why your table use a `DECIMAL` column, and not `FLOAT` one, I assume). For *exact* values, Python provide the [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#module-decimal) type. You should take a look at it.

Comment: I'm glad you've pointed out the discrepancy in using floats for monetary values. The reason floats is being used is because of my earlier post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057406/mysql-and-python-convert-string-value-to-int-to-float-or-what/17057737#17057737 after I implemented @theodox's code. If you take a look there's more clarity there. But now I'm concerned about this decimal/float issue. What would you suggest? I'm a beginner btw, hence decisions made.

Answer (score 0):

When you want `A1`, you can't concatenate like `'A' + 1`. As Sylvain just chimed in, `format` works:

```
'A{}'.format(1)
```

but in this case, the execute method provides its own way to handle this common issue.

```
execute('A%s', (1))
```

See the [documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) for more complete examples.